# Is there a way for typescript to type using broad keys of a defined object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
const obj: {[key: string]: string} = {foo: 'x', bar: 'y'};

type ObjType = keyof typeof obj;
```

Without modifying the type of `obj`, how can I make `ObjType` accept only "foo" or "bar" and not any string ?

Comment: You would have to modify the type of `obj` for this to work. No other way, sorry, because you already have lost the type information when you annotated it as `{ [key: string]: string }`.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done on typescript 4.8. You cannot constrain a type, and get a more specific version of that type to use in the same assignment.

The typical workaround is to use a generic function, which sort of sucks.

```
function makeObj<T extends { [key: string]: string }>(obj: T) {
    return obj
}

const obj = makeObj({foo: 'x', bar: 'y'})

type ObjType = keyof typeof obj // 'foo' | 'bar'
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.9.0-dev.20220914#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmB5ARgKwB4AVRTADykzABMBnRAb0QG0sBPALkTqgCcYYAOYBdbrwHDEAXwB8ACjgFuxAJRMAUIm2I+mKCD5Il+DdI0aICXohOIAvCgw4C8xsDhxuAcnLeANIi4qHw+7N7SqhZQ7AAOmIh4+MRxCY4ccMCIMfGZtgSIAPSFiN4ecN6IAD6lwXzeGkA)

---

However, the next version of typescript (4.9) seems likely to contain the `satisfies` operator. See [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920)

This will let you apply a constraint, and infer the more specific type all at once.

```
const obj = {foo: 'x', bar: 'y'} satisfies { [key: string]: string }

type ObjType = keyof typeof obj // 'foo' | 'bar'
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.9.0-dev.20220914#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAZiEAuGA5AB4EA0M8AhgE74ECeBAvjBJVAJYSYcCmEGGAG0A1r3r5o1DmADmAXUlRpcmEwBQ6qPQAOvGAHkkAFV360Y+iEwxte63CQwA9M8LYQBGAB9CVagRAA)

---

But either way, you will have to modify how `obj` is declared to make any of this work.

Answer (score 0):

Just let the inference do the job :

```
const obj = {foo: 'x', bar: 'y'};

type ObjType = keyof typeof obj; //  "foo" | "bar"
```